# How to get the path of the download folder using FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download, filestreamresult

I need to Log if a download was or not successful.
In a case which I specify the destination path is so easy, the problem is when the destination path is the default "Download" folder specified in the Browser used.

My code is something like this:

```
     ...
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     zipFile.Save(stream);
     zipFile.Dispose();
     stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     item.Log(LogLevels.Info, 101, button.MessageID, "Successful", **Download Path**);

     return File(stream, "application/zip", fileName);
```

What I download is a Zip file, but I need to Log also the destination

I read some posts about, but they didn't help me really...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to log where the client will save the file ? Because that is impossible.

Comment: THanks for your help!... 
I was confused about this stuff. Now I know it´s not possible.